# How to create a one-to-many relationship between a query and a table in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

[image]

Above is the Table "People"

[image]

Above is the SQL view of the Query "Count Country" based on Table "People"

[image]

Above is the datasheet view of the Query "Count Country" based on Table "People"

[image]

Above is another Table called "City List"

[image]

Why can't I create a one-to-many relationship between Query "Count Country" and Table "City List"?

Comment: You can, just drag the field from one query onto the matching field on the other query. It won't be a relationship that is enforceable , as both sources are queries not tables , hence the wizard gets confused. If you double click the join line you can change it from a Join to a left / right join.

Comment: Start by determining/explaining why you are trying to create this relationship. What functionality you are hoping to achieve with it.

Comment: I know it seems meaningless to build this relationship, it actually is just a simple example I created just for explaining my problem better (since my actual database is more complicated and confidential). In this example, I want to build a form based on Query "Count Country",  I can then select on any country, click on a button and it will take me to the linked table "City List" with only showing the cities of my selected country. To achieve this, I need to build the one-to-many relationship between Query "Count Country" and Table "City List" first. Let me know if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: Why do you need to count country from table People when a DISTINCT query of table CityList will return a unique record for each country? If you want a list of only the countries used in table People, then aggregating on table People would be appropriate. Still not clear what you are trying to accomplish. France shows in table People but not in CityList. Why aren't you saving ID of CityList into table People?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like cascading (dependent) comboboxes. So if you don't have a table of Countries, RowSource for cbxCountry can be `SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM CityList;`. Then RowSource for cbxCities filtered by cbxCountry `SELECT City FROM CityList WHERE Country=[cbxCountry];`. You will need code to requery cbxCity when moving to another record and/or when changing selection in cbxCountry.

If you want a form showing distinct country then RecordSource can be the same DISTINCT query. Then code to open a form for associated cities:

`DoCmd.OpenForm "Cities", , , "Country='" & Me.Country & "'"`

Answer (score 0):

You can only create a relationship with referential integrity between tables. Also, both fields must have the same data type and the field(s) on the left (the field(s) that you draggeed to the other side) must be the primary key of that table (or at least have a unique index that does not allow for Null values).

The only reason for creating a relationship without referential integrity is to tell Access how the data is related, so Access will join both tables (or as in your case the table and the query) automatically when you add both of them to a query. Also, Access might automatically create a "subdatasheet" when dealing with datasheets.

To "automatically" build the form that jumps to the cities, use the form wizard and add fields from both your query and your table.